# Nightmare JS stalls when used in a firebase function

Tags: javascript, firebase, web-scraping, google-cloud-functions, nightmare

I'm trying to do some scraping with NightmareJS from a firebase function. Here is my code (minimum verifiable example)

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()
const Nightmare =  require('nightmare');

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const nightmare =  Nightmare()
  return nightmare.goto('https://apple.com')
                  .end()
                  .then(function() {
                     console.log('success')
                     response.status(200).send("Script successfully completed")
                  })
                  .catch(function(data) {
                     console.log('error')
                     response.status(400).send('something went wrong' + data)
                  })
 })
```

This code works perfectly fine when I'm testing the function locally. The script visits the page and then triggers `then()` clause. However, if I deploy and trigger the function, it will get to the `nightmare.goto` line, and then stall. It doesn't throw an error (if it did, it would be caught by the catch clause and I would get a response). Instead it times out after 60s. What's going on there?

To explain for those not familiar with nightmareJS, `end()` turns the nightmare call chain into a promise. Again, the code works fine locally, which is the biggest clue. I thought it could be something with the fact that firebase doesn't allow outbound traffic on free plans, but after upgrading to blaze the problem is still there :(

Comment: Is that with a node8 runtime? You might need to open a ticket. Post the answer if you solve it.

Comment: Done. My experience with firebase support is pretty good so far, will see what they come back with.

Comment: The runtime is Node 6

Comment: Try switching to node 8